# Symfony2, Doctrine: Configuring repositories for multiple databases

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

let's say i have a lot (50+) of repository configurations that begin like this

```
// in src/Foo/BarBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Baz.orm.yml
Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Baz:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: Foo\BarBundle\Entity\BazRepository
  table: foo.bar.baz
```

i am working with more than one database, they are mostly clones of each other

```
// in app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        dbname:   foo
      alpha:
        dbname:   alpha
      bravo:
        dbname:   bravo
      charlie:
        dbname:   charlie
```

is there any way for me to change the way the repository configuration handles the table name dinamically ? I tried to inject app parameters in them, but it didn't quite worked.

```
// in app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
  database_active:   charlie

// in src/Foo/BarBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Baz.orm.yml
Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Baz:
  table: %database_active%.bar.baz
```

<sub>**[note]** i am working with MS SQL Server, but i think the same problem could be applied to PostgreSQL databases</sub>

Comment: is there any way i can close this question ? two days later i discovered that what i was doing was considered a hax, so i moved away from this coding structure